# sort_value working on Name column but not Number column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, columnsorting

When try to sort my dataframe by the column "Number" i get the error code

> 1708         # Check for duplicates
>
> KeyError: 'Number'

the dataframe looks something like this

```
Number Name City Sex

3 Jay A M

1 Marry A F

5 John B M
```

Number is int64 and the rest are objects

```
df.sort_values(by=['Number']) --> error

df.sort_values(by=['Name']) --> works

df.sort_values(by=['City']) --> error

df.sort_values(by=['Sex']) --> works
```

What i  am looking for is something like this

```
Number Name City Sex

  1 Marry A F

  3 Jay A M

  5 John B M
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the precise output of `print(df.columns)`. "the dataframe looks something like this..." isn't sufficient for us to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to make a DataFrame like yours and sort it & it works to sort by `Number` column:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Number':[3,1,5],
                'Name':['Jay','Marry','John'],
                'City':['A','A','B'],
                'Sex':['M','F','M']})
print(df)
print(df.Number.dtype)
df=df.sort_values(by=['Number'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Number   Name City Sex
0       3    Jay    A   M
1       1  Marry    A   F
2       5   John    B   M

int64

   Number   Name City Sex
1       1  Marry    A   F
0       3    Jay    A   M
2       5   John    B   M
```

Maybe there is a white space in your columns, try this before sorting:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: df.columns=df.columns.str.strip() worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, will be better if you give me up vote. :D